# Adding row in HTML for table Not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs, forms

I'm trying to add a couple of buttons to the top of my page: Save and Cancel. They are to come into display only after hitting the Submit button on the Customer Information panel. However, it only pushes down the Customer Information panel and i need the Search for Plan panel to also be pushed down one row so the tops of each of the panels stay level. Here is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="MchPlanAddController">
<!--<a href="#/MchPlan">BACK</a>-->
<h3>UNDERWRITING RULES MAINTENANCE - Add Plan Information</h3>

<div class="col-lg-8">
    <table style="width:100%; table-layout:auto">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:bottom">

                <div ng-if="vm.customer" class="panel" style="margin-left:15px">

                    <button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn"
                            ng-click="vm.save()"
                            title="Save pending changes to any and all todolists">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Save
                    </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" ng-click="vm.cancel()"
                            title="Discard changes and refresh from the server">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Cancel
                    </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <span class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="vm.getChangesCount()">
                        Unsaved changes: {{vm.getChangesCount()}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%; table-layout:auto">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Customer Information<span ng-if="vm.customer">: {{vm.customer.CustomerName}}</span></div>
                    <form name="vm.MchPlanStartForm" ng-submit="vm.getCustomer(vm.MchPlanStartForm.customerNumber);" class="form-horizontal" style="margin:15px">
                        <fieldset ng-disabled="vm.MchPlanStartForm.disabled">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Number: </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.MchPlanStartForm.customerNumber" class="form-control" required />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Effective Date of Change: </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="date" ng-model="vm.changeEffectiveDate" class="form-control" required />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn pull-left">Submit</button>
                            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="vm.loadingCustomer"></i>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </td>
            <!--<td style="vertical-align:bottom">

                <div ng-if="vm.customer" class="panel" style="margin-left:15px">

                    <button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn"
                            ng-click="vm.save()"
                            title="Save pending changes to any and all todolists">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Save
                    </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" ng-click="vm.cancel()"
                            title="Discard changes and refresh from the server">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Cancel
                    </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <span class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="vm.getChangesCount()">
                        Unsaved changes: {{vm.getChangesCount()}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>-->
        </tr>
    </table>

<div class="panel panel-default" ng-if="vm.customer">
    <table class="table " data-gps-droppable="vm.dropOnMch(dragEl, dropEl)">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Customer Number</th>
                <th>PlanCode</th>
                <th>Contract Number</th>
                <th>Plan Effective Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Status Date</th>
                <th>Trust Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="plan in vm.mchPlans">
            <td><i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="vm.remove(plan)"></i></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="plan.CustomerNumber"></span></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="plan.PlanCode" />          </td>
            <td><span ng-bind="plan.ContractNumber" />    </td>
            <td><input type="date" ng-model="plan.PlanEffectiveDate" z-validate /> </td>
            <td><select ng-model="plan.PlanStatus" ng-options="status for status in vm.planStatuses" z-validate />        </td>
            <td><input type="date" ng-model="plan.PlanStatusDate" z-validate />    </td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="plan.TrustNumber" z-validate />       </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="99">Drop Plans Here to add them.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</div>

<!--Search for Plan-->
<div class="col-lg-4 ">
    <div class="panel panel-default ">
        <div class="panel-heading">Search for plan</div>
        <form name="PlanDesignSearchForm" class="form-horizontal" style="margin:15px">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Contract Number: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="contractnumber" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">PlanCode:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="plancode" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" ng-click="vm.searchPlans(contractnumber, plancode)"         class="btn pull-right">Search</button>
                <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="vm.searchingPlans"></i>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-if="vm.planDesigns">
        <table class="table ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Contract</th>
                    <th>PlanCode</th>
                    <th>Orig Eff Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="planDesign in vm.planDesigns" data-gps-draggable>
                <td>{{planDesign.ContractNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{planDesign.PlanCode}}</td>
                <td>{{planDesign.OriginalEffectiveDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-if="vm.planDesigns.length==0">
                <td colspan="3">No plans found</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

<style>
.input-contain input {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to remove the buttons from the div that it was in. The div it was wrapped in was only 8/12 of the screen, hence why it only moved 8/12 of the screen down. So, i just moved it to outside of that and gave it its own div.

Here is a snippet of code that fixes it:

```
<div ng-controller="MchPlanAddController">
<!--<a href="#/MchPlan">BACK</a>-->
<h3>UNDERWRITING RULES MAINTENANCE - Add Plan Information</h3>


<div ng-if="vm.customer" class="panel" style="margin-left:15px">

    <button class="btn btn-success navbar-btn"
            ng-click="vm.save()"
            title="Save pending changes to any and all todolists">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Save
    </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" ng-click="vm.cancel()"
            title="Discard changes and refresh from the server">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Cancel
    </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <span class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="vm.getChangesCount()">
        Unsaved changes: {{vm.getChangesCount()}}
    </span>
</div>


<div class="col-lg-8">

    <table style="width:100%; table-layout:auto">
        <tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your buttons in a separate row.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     ... your buttons here ...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
     ... your panels here ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     ... your panels here ...
  </div>
</div>
```